# Give a recursive definition for the set of finite binary strings with an even number of 0s followed by 1s

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science

> Give a recursive definition for the set $S$ consisting of finite bit-strings containing an even number of $0$s, and all $0$s (if present) appear before all $1$s.  That is, $001\in S$ and $1\in S$, but $01111\not\in S$, and $01100011\not\in S$.

I was thinking the basis step would be empty string is a member of $S$, but I don't really know how to do the problem.

Comment: You could easily put that question into text.  URL's are not terribly persistent and this question will be worthless if the URL breaks.  As is, the question shows complete lack of effort.

Answer (score 1):

The base case is the empty string, which is a member of S.

Now everything that has 2 zeros before an existing member of S is also a member of S.

Everything that has 1 one after an existing member of S is also a member of S.

This should give you every member of S.

(If you don't want to use the empty string as a base case because it's not a finite bit-string, you could also use two separate base cases, 00 and 1, and still apply the previous two rules.)